# рельеф объекта canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
canv=Canvas(root,width=200,height=50,cursor='pencil')
canv.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.4375)
Label(canv,relief='raised').place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)
canv2=Canvas(root,relief='raised')
canv2.place(relx=0.375,relwidth=0.25,rely=0.65,relheight=0.2)
canv2.create_oval(10,10,90,70)
```

[image]

Никакой ошибки не происходит,canvas просто не становится выпуклым,и вообще не реагирует на параметр relief,например,он не становится выпуклым назад(как нажатая кнопка),когда я присваиваю значение SUNKEN этому параметру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать ширину границы (по-умолчанию она равна 0), тогда рельеф будет отображаться:

```
canv2=Canvas(root, relief='raised', borderwidth=1)
canv2.place(relx=0.375,relwidth=0.25,rely=0.65,relheight=0.2)
canv2.create_oval(10,10,90,70)
```